# How to share data variables between child components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-stepper

I have parent component `addUser.vue` and it contains `v-stepper` and I want to refactor `v-stepper-content` into couple of child components `StepperOne.vue`, `StepperTwo.vue`, `StepperThree.vue` like this

adddUser.vue

```
<v-stepper>
   <v-stepper-header>
   </v-stepper-header>
   <v-stepper-items>
     <stepper-one>
     </stepper-one>
     <stepper-two>
     </stepper-two>
     <stepper-three>
     </stepper-three>
</v-stepper>

//normally we just do this and use `v-model` but child-parent component thing is complicated
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
     firstname: "",
     lastname: "",
     select: null
     }
  }
}

</script>
```

And these three child components use the same data variables, `firstname: "",` `lastname: "",`and `select: null (for gender)`. How do I share this variables between these three child components into parent component?

What's the better approach?

Comment: The usual `v-model` way would work just fine here probably?

Answer (score 0):

Like answered before you should be able to share data with a propperty and event/emit combination. As a sugar syntax you could use v-model or sync

Another way is to use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) as a state for the data you could use a getter to obtain data in different components and use setters (commit) to set data to the store